# Dynamically hide a WPF TabItem

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, tabitem

Let's say I have a very simple XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 1" Visibility="Hidden">
                <TextBlock>shfsdjkfhksh jkfhd sfjdklh sfjdkh fjdkh fdjhf </TextBlock>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 2" Visibility="Hidden">
                <TextBlock>3807689vthvybhgthugbbjgkngoebt4uibn54</TextBlock>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

If I just set `TabItem`'s visibility to hidden, the content inside that tab does not hide.

Is there a way to hide tab header and its content together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by binding the Visibility to the parent control.  If you are using a view model, you can bind the visibility to a property in your view model and use the property for both the TabItem and TextBlock.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem x:Name="tab1" Header="Tab 1" Visibility="Hidden">
            <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding Path=Visibility, ElementName=tab1}">shfsdjkfhksh jkfhd sfjdklh sfjdkh fjdkh fdjhf</TextBlock>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Any idea what is wrong with `<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=Visibility}">shfsdjkfhksh jkfhd sfjdklh sfjdkh fjdkh fdjhf </TextBlock>` it doesn't see to work for me.

Comment: You are going to save yourself a lot of headaches by implementing a view model and binding to properties from your view model.  A lot of problems in WPF are simplified by having a view model.

Comment: I know, I need to deliver some POC quickly. In real work I will use PRISM.

Comment: The relative source is not finding the ancestor type because it is looking at ancestor level 1 and not finding a TabItem.  You can use a utility like Snoop, to check the status of your bindings.  I don't really think using the FindAncestor is really appropriate here because this is something you typically will use while working in templates.  Also, if anything about your UI changes you are almost guaranteed to bust the binding.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `Visibility` to `Hidden` for the selected/active tab, you'll need to select a different tab, e.g.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem x:Name="T1" Header="Tab 1" Visibility="Hidden" >
            <TextBlock>1111111111111111111</TextBlock>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="T2" Header="Tab 2" IsSelected="True">
            <TextBlock>22222222222222222222222</TextBlock>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

You do not need to hide the content of the `TabItem` provided that the `TabItem` is hidden and unselected.

Comment: What about I want to hide both? I have nothing to select then.

Comment: @hardywang Then set `Visibility` on the `TabControl` instead. A `TabControl` without any tabs is a very strange design.

Comment: I want to hide by c# code but not hide. tab2.isselected=true; tab1.visibility=visibility.hidden;